# How to access variables declared in one sub in another sub in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

In the following code, I want to access `ExcelWorkbook1` declared in `Sub OpenExcel` in `Sub SelectRangeOfCells`. Please help me with the same.

```
Public Sub OpenExcel(ByVal Path As String, ByVal Filename As String)
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()

    xlApp.Visible = True
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!")

    End If
    Dim MyFile As String = Dir$(Path + "\" + Filename)
    If MyFile = Filename Then
        Dim ExcelWorkbook1 As Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path + "\" + Filename)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Excel not found!")
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub SelectRangeOfCells(ByVal Sheet As String, ByVal Range As String)
    ExcelWorkbook1.Worksheets(Sheet).activate
End Sub
```

This shows error in `SelectRangeOfCells` Sub that `ExcelWorkbook1` is not declared.

Comment: You can't.  No variable can be accessed outside of the scope it was declared in.  If you want to access a variable in more then one method then it must be declared outside all of them.  You can still set the variable where you currently are but you must declare it at the class level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kinda basic.

Of course, you cannot access `ExcelWorkbook1` from another sub because it is declared locally in the `OpenExcel` sub.

To access `ExceWorkBook1` using both subs, you must declare it outside of those two subs.

```
Dim ExcelWorkbook1 As Workbook 'put this here

Public Sub OpenExcel(ByVal Path As String, ByVal Filename As String)
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()

xlApp.Visible = True
If xlApp Is Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!")

End If
Dim MyFile As String = Dir$(Path + "\" + Filename)
If MyFile = Filename Then
    ExcelWorkbook1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path + "\" + Filename) 'The declaration here is moved outside of the sub, granting access to the other subs
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Excel not found!")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: and can you tell me if i have opened to Excel workbooks simultaneously, ExcelWorkbook1 will always refer to the most recent workbook. How do i refer to both of them separately?

Comment: yes and then copy data from one to another. But i refer through excelworkbook1, it will only refer to one of the workbooks right?

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `ExcelWorkbook1` as a class property then use it in yours methods:

```
Property ExcelWorkbook1 As Workbook

Public Sub OpenExcel(ByVal Path As String, ByVal Filename As String)
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()

    xlApp.Visible = True
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!")
    End If
    Dim MyFile As String = Dir$(Path + "\" + Filename)
    If MyFile = Filename Then
        ExcelWorkbook1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path + "\" + Filename)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Excel not found!")
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub SelectRangeOfCells(ByVal Sheet As String, ByVal Range As String)
    ExcelWorkbook1.Worksheets(Sheet).activate
End Sub
```

More about properties in VB.NET you can learn from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8ae41a4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)