# Making public after being Private - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Currently in the process of "self teaching" visual basic so apologies for the basic question

Maybe I am going about this the wrong way but I want to use `btnTA_StartLog` to create a file and activate `Timer1` to log data in a specified interval.  Problem being `outlog` is only defined in `btnTA_startLog` and not in the other 2 subs. How can I make the recently declared `outlog` public and accessible to the other subs?

```vb
Public Sub btnTA_StartLog_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTA_StartLog.Click
    Dim file As String = GetFileName(False, "csv", "Data Output")
    Dim outlog As IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(file, True)
    Timer1.Start()
    btnTA_StartLog.Enabled = False
    btbTA_LoggingStop.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    outlog.WriteLine(CStr(DateTime.Now) & "," & CStr(txbTA_Delivered_ml.Text) & "," & CStr(MyTC.Data.Temperature))
End Sub

Private Sub btbTA_LoggingStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btbTA_LoggingStop.Click
    Timer1.Stop()
    outlog.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access variables declared in one sub in another sub in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484109/how-to-access-variables-declared-in-one-sub-in-another-sub-in-vb-net)

Comment: Yes and no. I was hoping to declare outlog during runtime with a user selecting a save location and not explicitly define it prior.    More specially, I guess "file" would be defined like this

Comment: No need to keep the file open (that's what StreamWriter does until you explicitly close it). Declare `file` at the class level (you should really use a different name, e.g., `filePath`) and then use `IO.File.AppendAllText(filePath, "some text here" & Environment.NewLine)` anywhere you want.

Comment: What you could do is have a logging class with methods to add an entry to the log and close the log. Then you create an instance of that class and tell it what to do: it has the reference to the writer inside it, so the rest of the code doesn't need to know about it. But you would still need the variable that holds the reference to the logger to be at the class level, as shown in [the answer by jmoreno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71316112/1115360).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be at the class level one way or another.

```vb
Private outlog As IO.StreamWriter

Public Sub btnTA_StartLog_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTA_StartLog.Click
    Dim file As String = GetFileName(False, "csv", "Data Output")
    outlog = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(file, True)
    Timer1.Start()
    btnTA_StartLog.Enabled = False
    btbTA_LoggingStop.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    outlog.WriteLine(CStr(DateTime.Now) & "," & CStr(txbTA_Delivered_ml.Text) & "," & CStr(MyTC.Data.Temperature))
End Sub

Private Sub btbTA_LoggingStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btbTA_LoggingStop.Click
    Timer1.Stop()
    outlog.Close()
End Sub
```

I used a private field, but it could be a private property.  It could be contained in another object for which you have class level reference to.

Answer (score 0):

not a vb.net person so I dont know the exact syntax but the rules are the same for c# which I do know.

Define outlog at the form level, ie outside any functions, in that way all functions can use it.